# Vector rotation in 3D

Tags: vector, 3d, rotation, resolve

I have two points, A and B, in 3D space, and I know the magnitude and direction of vector **AB** (in x,y,z coordinates). I have a force **F** at A, and I know its magnitude and direction. I can resolve this force into the force along the line **AB**, denoted **F_par_AB**, by getting the dot product between the force at A and the unit vector **AB**, and hence know that magnitude and direction. The force perpendicular to **AB**, denoted **F_perp_AB** is then found by vector addition (**F_par_AB** + **F_Perp_AB** = **F**).

My issue now is that I want to resolve **F_perp_AB** into two components, lets call them **vec1** and **vec2**, that are both orthogonal to eachother and orthogonal to **AB**. I think this can be achieved by some sort of vector rotation, where I make a new coordinate system x'y'z'. I define x' to be in the direction of **AB**, y' to be in the direction of **vec1** and z' to be in the direction of **vec2**. Knowing the direction of **AB** in the original xyz coordinate system, is it possible to do some sort of rotation so that I can resolve the total force **F** into the force along x' (which is along **AB** and the force in this direction is known), y' and z'?

Thanks

Comment: This question seems to be purely mathematical in nature, so https://math.stackexchange.com/ seems like a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

The [cross-product of 2 vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) **by definition is perpendicular to both vectors** (assuming the vectors are not parallel)

> In mathematics, the cross product or vector product (occasionally
>   directed area product to emphasize the geometric significance) is a
>   binary operation on two vectors in three-dimensional space ( R 3 ) ,
>   the cross product, a × b  (read "a cross b"), is a vector that is
>   perpendicular to both a  and b  and thus normal to the plane
>   containing them. It has many applications in mathematics, physics,
>   engineering, and computer programming. It should not be confused with
>   the dot product (projection product).
>
> If two vectors have the same direction (or have the exact opposite
>   direction from one another, i.e. are not linearly independent) or if
>   either one has zero length, then their cross product is zero.

So the third vector perpendicular is simply the cross-product of **AB** and **F_perp_AB** and by definition is perpendicular to both of them. So it defines a 3D coordinate system.

Then you can also normalize to have unit length and so on if you like.

**UPDATE:** *I am looking to resolve F_perp_AB into two vectors, which are perpendicular to each other and also to vector AB*.

In this case you can take any random vactor perpendicular to AB and find the dually perpendicular to that by substracting the projections on AB and so on.

For example you can always take the 1st vector to be F_perp_AB itself and the other vector to be the vector perpnedicular to both (eg cross-product). There is no unique answer to that, any combination is valid without any other criteria which restrict selection.

Cross-product is a general way to construct perpndicular vector to 2 vectors.

**NOTE** There is no reason given that the cross-product of F_perp_AB and AB (lets call it ZZ) cannot be computed to give the 3rd axis and resolve F into these 3 axes (F will have zero coords on the 3rd axis ZZ but again there is no unique solution, it is acceptable solution). Any random rotation can be done for the vectors F_perp_AB and ZZ and this will give another equivalent 3D coordinate system where F will NOT have zero coords on 3rd axis. There is no unique solution without further criteria given.

A [related post on physics.se](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77354/how-do-i-split-a-vector-into-components-parallel-and-perpendicular-to-a-known-li)

Comment: Thanks Nikos, but I am not looking for the vector that is perpendicular to both AB and and F_perp_AB, I am looking to resolve F_perp_AB into two vectors, which are perpendicular to each other and also to vector AB.

Comment: @Anna, the cross-product will give you the 3rd perpendicular vector and then you can analyse the force perpendicular to that 3d axis simply by dot product

Comment: @Anna, else simply take the crorss-product of F and AB and analyse F into components of that coordinate system

Comment: If you consider that I have a tape with a rectangular cross section, carrying an electric current. A and B are two points on the tape, in a straight line. The current produces a magnetic field. The magnitude and direction of the field at point A is know (Force at A). I also know the force along AB from the dot product of F and AB, and the force perpendicular to AB. Though I know that the force is perpendicular to AB, I do not know what direction it is in, as it could be in any direction in the plane normal to AB. Consider the 2D cross section of the tape; FperpAB is in this plane. I

Comment: . . . cont. . I want to resolve FperpAB into components that are parallel to the base of the tape face and the height of the tape face (i.e. vec1 and vec2 from above). I do not know the directions of vec1 and vec2, but I know that vec1, vec2 and AB are all orthogonal to each other

Comment: there is no unqiue solution without further criteria to restrict selection of vetcors. Any random vectors will do including having F_perp_AB and 0 as the 2 perpendicular vectors or linear combinations of them

Comment: @Anna, see my updated answer. There is no unqiue solution but I gave ways to construct any acceptable solution matching the descritpion